# Merge several data frames having the same variables and observations

Tags: r, csv, merge, dataframe

I have several `CSV` files for each year. Each file contains the same variables and observations.

```
df14 <- data.frame(name = c("one", "two", "three"), A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4, 2, 1), C = c(0, 1, 1))
df15 <- data.frame(name = c("one", "two", "three"), A = c(3,1,1), C = c(0, 0, 1), B = c(8, 5, 5))
```

Suppose `df14` & `df15` represent years 2014 & 2015 respectively.

**Note:** the variables are not recorded in the same order.

What I'd like to do is see how each variable (A, B, C) are changing by year for each `name`.

Is there a way to combine these in one data frame? Should I simply `rbind` them?

**Update:**

One thing I could do is assign the years as a new variable and `rbind` but is it good practice?

```
df14$year <- 2014; df15$year <- 2015
df <- rbind(df14, df15)
```

which gives:

> ```
>    name A B C year
>    one 1 4 0 2014
>    two 2 2 1 2014
>    three 3 1 1 2014
>    one 3 8 0 2015
>    two 1 5 0 2015
>    three 1 5 1 2015
> ```

Comment: What about the observations? They are for the same attributes (ie; one, two, three)

Comment: I could do this with df1$year <- 2014 & df2$year <- 2015 then rbind. But we're back to the previous question. I'll update the question to include the result of this option.

Comment: You should put them in a list to start, not as separate data frames. [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061). Then you can use `do.call` with `rbind` or `dplyr::bind_rows` to combine them.

Comment: @Gregor that's a good post. I'll be rechecking it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
years_2_digt <- 14:15

DT <- 
rbindlist(lapply(years_2_digt, function(y) {
  get(paste0("df", y)) %>% 
  setDT %>% 
  .[, year := y] %>%
  setkeyv("name")
}))


DT.molt <- reshape2::melt(DT, id.vars=c("name", "year"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=DT.molt, aes(x=year, color=variable, y=value)) + 
    geom_line() + geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(name ~ .) + 
    ggtitle("Change by year and name")
```

[image]

Comment: The setcolorder part is new to me; thanks.

As for the others I can't see how the result is different.

The thing is that all frames have exactly the same variables (3 in the example). Moreover the observations are exactly 3 (in this case). The observations (rows) are represented by the "name" col. They are names of districts.

Comment: @user10853 The `setcolorder` function is from the `data.table` package. It's not clear from your question what you want the ultimate result to be.  If you could show what your desired output would be, it would be easier to help

Comment: I restated it now: see how each variable (A, B, C) are changing by year for each "name".

Comment: You indeed managed to get the result. Could you please explain what the function does?
Maybe there's no way to do what I've been thinking; the best option is a relational database i guess.
Any way I'll mark your answer as a solution. Any new suggestions are appreciated too.

Comment: to be specific, this part is weird: `setDT %>% "["(j=`:=`(year, y)) %>%  setkeyv("name")`

Comment: also how can I plot it for only one `name` ?

Comment: The middle command of the "weird" part has a variant I think I've seen folks use: `setDT %>% .[,year:=y] %>% setkeyv("name")`. @user10853 All three commands are from the `data.table` package (loaded in the first line).

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically add the year column to each data frame and then rbind them. Here's an example that relies on being able to get the year corresponding to each data frame from the file name. Here, I've stored you sample data frames in a list. In your real use case, you'd read the csv files into a list using something like `df.list = sapply(vector_of_file_names, read.csv)`.

```
df.list = list(df14=df14, df15=df15)

df.list = lapply(1:length(df.list), function(i) {
  df.list[[i]] = data.frame(df.list[[i]], 
                            year = 2000 + as.numeric(gsub(".*(\\d{2})\\.csv","\\1", names(df.list)[[i]])))
})

df = do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Comment: If you want a list, is there a reason to use `sapply` over `lapply` (in your first paragraph)?

Comment: So that the name of the file will become the name of the corresponding list element, which I then use in the function to get the year.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example within one `lapply`:

Make some dummy `CSV` files:

```
df14 <- data.frame(name = c("one", "two", "three"), A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4, 2, 1), C = c(0, 1, 1))
df15 <- data.frame(name = c("one", "two", "three"), A = c(3,1,1), C = c(0, 0, 1), B = c(8, 5, 5))
df16 <- data.frame(name = c("one", "two", "three"), C = c(1,2,3), B = c(4, 2, 1), A = c(0, 1, 1))
df17 <- data.frame(name = c("one", "two", "three"), C = c(3,1,1), A = c(0, 0, 1), B = c(8, 5, 5))
#get dataframe names
myNames <- ls()[grepl("df",ls())]
lapply(myNames, function(i){write.csv(get(i),paste0(i,".csv"),row.names = FALSE)})
```

Solution: read `CSV` files, fix columns using sort, then `rbind` them into one dataframe:

```
#Solution - read CSV, fix columns, rbind
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(list.files(".","^df\\d*.csv"),
               function(i){
                 d <- read.csv(i)
                 res <- d[,sort(colnames(d))]
                 cbind(res,FileName=i)
               }))
# output
#    A B C  name FileName
# 1  1 4 0   one df14.csv
# 2  2 2 1   two df14.csv
# 3  3 1 1 three df14.csv
# 4  3 8 0   one df15.csv
# 5  1 5 0   two df15.csv
# 6  1 5 1 three df15.csv
# 7  0 4 1   one df16.csv
# 8  1 2 2   two df16.csv
# 9  1 1 3 three df16.csv
# 10 0 8 3   one df17.csv
# 11 0 5 1   two df17.csv
# 12 1 5 1 three df17.csv
```

Comment: The other answers also basically do it in one command (rbindlist+lapply or do.call rbind + lapply), except for the reading in part, but +1 because this is exactly what I often do (tossing file names in as temporary a "src" column).